# How and where Flutter Framework internally call StatefulWidget's state's build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that `StatelessWidget` define's `build` method in it's class but `StatefulWidget` doesn't define `build` method directly whereas it is defined in it's `State` class so *how and where* in the the Flutter Framework(need the the location in flutter source code) the `build` method of the `StatefulWidget`'s state is called.

Comment: call `debugPrintStack()` top level function inside `State.build` method and see the logs

Comment: @pskink Thank you, it really helped me figure out how Flutter Framework internally manages to call the appropriate `build` function (e.g., [StatelessWidget.build] or [State.build]) for their widget.